# Ubuntu network stop working after heavy load of packets received

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

My LAN has 2 PCs installed, Ubuntu 10.04 and Windows XP. I run the server on Ubuntu, and client on Windows XP. Because I am doing stress test, so the client will keep sending tons of packets to server.

**The strange thing is**: After few seconds, the client program crash because of insufficient network buffer, the server is still ok. But after that I cant connect Ubuntu PC anymore until I restart it. And I check the router, the led for the Ubuntu PC is always ON (not blinking), look like it is jam already.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any anti-flood protection enabled by default on ubuntu.

Try connect both hosts directly with crossed cable (without any router or switch). Some home routers does not handle very well heavy traffic. I'm not sure if it will solve your problem but it's worth to try.